# Flat indexing of all but first dimension with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matlab, indexing, matrix-indexing

Is there some way to use flat indexing for the remaining dimensions with NumPy? I'm trying to translate the following MATLAB function to Python

```matlab
function [indices, weights] = locate(values, gridpoints)
    indices = ones(size(values));
    weights = zeros([2, size(values)]);

    for ix = 1:numel(values)
        if values(ix) <= gridpoints(1)
            indices(ix) = 1;
            weights(:, ix) = [1; 0];
        elseif values(ix) >= gridpoints(end)
            indices(ix) = length(gridpoints) - 1;
            weights(:, ix) = [0; 1];
        else
            indices(ix) = find(gridpoints <= values(ix), 1, 'last');    
            weights(:, ix) = ...
                [gridpoints(indices(ix) + 1) - values(ix); ...
                 values(ix) - gridpoints(indices(ix))] ...
                / (gridpoints(indices(ix) + 1) - gridpoints(indices(ix)));
        end
    end
end
```

but I can't wrap my head around what the NumPy equivalent of MATLAB's `weights(:, ix)` would be---that is, linear indexing only in the remaining dimensions.

I was hoping that the syntax could be directly translated, but suppose that `values` is a 3-by-4 array, then `weights` becomes a 2-by-3-by-4 array. In MATLAB, `weights(:, ix)` is then a 2-by-1 array, whereas in Python `weights[:, ix]` is a 2-by-3 array.

I think that I have handled everything else in the function below.

```py
import numpy as np


def locate(values, gridpoints):
    indices = np.zeros(np.shape(values), dtype=int)
    weights = np.zeros((2,) + np.shape(values))

    for ix in range(values.size):
        if values.flat[ix] <= gridpoints[0]:
            indices.flat[ix] = 0
            # weights[:, ix] = [1, 0]
        elif values.flat[ix] >= gridpoints[-1]:
            indices.flat[ix] = gridpoints.size - 2
            # weights[:, ix] = [0, 1]
        else:
            indices.flat[ix] = (
                np.argwhere(gridpoints <= values.flat[ix]).flatten()[-1]
            )
            # weights[:, ix] = (
            #         np.array([gridpoints[indices.flat[ix] + 1] - values.flat[ix],
            #                   values.flat[ix] - gridpoints[indices.flat[ix]]])
            #         / (gridpoints[indices.flat[ix] + 1] - gridpoints[indices.flat[ix]])
            # )

    return indices, weights
```

Do you have any suggestions? Perhaps I'm just thinking about the problem all wrong. I have also tried to write the code as simply as possible as I intend to use Numba to speed it up later.

Comment: `ix` is just a scalar, so the equivalent for `x(:,ix)` in MATLAB would be `x[:,ix]` in Python (take care of off-by-one errors due to 1-based vs 0-based indexing). There's no remaining dimensions or something here. In MATLAB, this takes column `ix` from a 2D matrix, which is trivial in NumPy as well.

Comment: @Adriaan Not quite. Suppose in MATLAB (Python) `values = zeros(3, 4)` (`values = np.zeros((3, 4))`. Then `weights` is a 2-by-3-by-4 array and `weights(:, 1)` a 2-by-1 array (`weights[:, 1]` a 2-by-3 array).

Comment: In that case you can either do `weights[:, :, ix]` expliticly or `weights[..., ix]`, although I'm not familiar enough with Python whether front-ellipses work.

Comment: @Adriaan I think that both of those would give me 2-by-3-by-1 arrays in the example from my last comment. But thank you for trying!

Comment: Could you please [edit] the question to make a [mcve]? I.e. take everything out except this indexing issue and add some sample data (`rand(3,4)` for example), showing what MATLAB does and what you currently obtain in Python? All the loops and `if` statements seem irrelevant to this indexing issue, making it harder to grasp.

Comment: There isn't a direct `numpy` equivalent.  It's MATLAB that's playing funny games here.

Comment: To understand what MATLAB is doing I'd have to run the code line by line in an Octave session, paying attention to shapes at each.

Comment: @hpaulj These “funny games” is just linear indexing, which is terribly useful and I often miss when working with NumPy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70391820/flat-indexing-of-all-but-first-dimension-with-numpy?noredirect=1#comment124434876_70391820), there doesn't seem to be a direct NumPy equivalent. In lack thereof, the best I can think of is to reshape the `weights` array as in the code below and the suggestion from [NumPy for Matlab Users](http://scipy.github.io/old-wiki/pages/NumPy_for_Matlab_Users.html#line-208).

```
import numpy as np


def locate(values, gridpoints):
    indices = np.zeros(values.shape, dtype=int)
    weights = np.zeros((2, values.size))  # Temporarily make weights 2-by-N

    for ix in range(values.size):
        if values.flat[ix] <= gridpoints[0]:
            indices.flat[ix] = 0
            weights[:, ix] = [1, 0]
        elif values.flat[ix] >= gridpoints[-1]:
            indices.flat[ix] = gridpoints.size - 2
            weights[:, ix] = [0, 1]
        else:
            indices.flat[ix] = (
                np.argwhere(gridpoints <= values.flat[ix]).flatten()[-1]
            )
            weights[:, ix] = (
                    np.array([gridpoints[indices.flat[ix] + 1] - values.flat[ix],
                              values.flat[ix] - gridpoints[indices.flat[ix]]])
                    / (gridpoints[indices.flat[ix] + 1] - gridpoints[indices.flat[ix]])
            )
    
    # Give weights correct dimensions
    weights.shape = (2,) + values.shape
    
    return indices, weights
```

Comment: This is indeed the only solution AFAIK. Python doesn’t do linear indexing, which is what you are doing in MATLAB in the 2nd and 3rd dimensions.